# Relación de tablas en R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

Buenas tardes,
Me gustaría relacionar dos dataframes:

```
 Df1. Lugar Animal Número 
       1. Perro     1
       2. Gato      0  
       3. Loro      2


Df2. Lugar Animal  

       1. Perro    
       1. Perro       
       2. Gato
       2. Gato
       2. Loro
       2. Gato  
       2. Loro    
       3. Perro   
       3. Perro  
       3. Loro 
       3. Loro
```

de tal forma que el valor numérico del dataframe1 aparezca de manera correspondiente en una columna adicional en el dataframe 2 dependiendo de la especie.

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilisar el `match(x)` con `x` los valores a ser igualada.devuelve un vector de las posiciones de (primeras) coincidencias de su primer argumento en su segundo. 
Por lo tanto, puede usar el índice devuelto para crear una nueva columna

`nuevaDf$nuevaColumna <- df$valorAñadir[match(nuevaDf$cosa,Df$cosa)]`

Con su ejemplo :

```
Animal  = c("Perro", "Gato", "Loro")
Numero = c(1,0,2)

Df1 = data.frame(Animal,Numero)

Animal = c("Perro","Perro","Gato","Gato","Loro","Gato","Loro","Perro","Perro","Loro","Loro" )


Df2 = data.frame(Animal)

df_lista$index <- df$Numero[match(df_lista$Animal, df$Animal)]

print(df_lista)
```

Output :

```
   Animal index
1   Perro     1
2   Perro     1
3    Gato     0
4    Gato     0
5    Loro     2
6    Gato     0
7    Loro     2
8   Perro     1
9   Perro     1
10   Loro     2
11   Loro     2
```

Comment: ¡¡¡eso es!!! muchas gracias Marine1.

Comment: En el caso que aparezca en el Df1 la especie ratón y no en el df_lista, al ejecutar el código me aparece en la nueva dataframe el index NA ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se haga el reemplazo cuando no está esa especie en el df_lista?